# Getting an array pointer from std::vector<glm::vec3> with the type of float

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c++11, vector

I have a `std::vector<glm::vec3>` and I want to get an array pointer from it with the type of float.

If the std::vector contents would be:

```
std::vector[0] = vec3(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f)
std::vector[1] = vec3(0.4f, 0.5f, 0.6f)
std::vector[2] = vec3(0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f)
```

Then this is what the array pointer would return with the current index specified:

```
array[0] = 0.1f
array[1] = 0.2f
array[2] = 0.3f
array[3] = 0.4f
array[4] = 0.5f
array[5] = 0.6f
array[6] = 0.7f
array[7] = 0.8f
array[8] = 0.9f
```

If this is possible, what is the most common way to achieve it?

Comment: Make a new `vector` from these 3 `vector`s.

Comment: But I don't want a copy of data

Comment: `float * ptr = &vec[0];` ?

Comment: make a simple wrapper that does array arithmetic for you.... also your code is wrong, you cannot do std::vector[0]

Comment: @Jaa-c are you suggesting an array of float pointers to each float in the vector of vectors?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl You could give me more information about that. And that is not the code. That is how I showed you the contents of the vector

Comment: pointer arithmetics is that you are basically doing translation from lets say 7 to vec[2], x or what is the coresponding member of vec3 in for x coordinate. be sure to return a reference and not a value so that you can modify array...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vec;
vec.push_back(glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f));
vec.push_back(glm::vec3(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f));
vec.push_back(glm::vec3(0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f));

float *flat_array = &vec[0].x;

for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    std::cout << flat_array[i] << std::endl;
```

Assuming that a glm::vec3 contains three tightly packed floats you can get a pointer to the first element of the first vec. This pointer can be indexed like an array.

Beware if glm::vec3 contains doubles or other member variables. In this case the pointer magic would fail.

Comment: `glm::vec3` contains only floats, so it will work. Also `vec[0].x` and `vec[0][0]` will work both.

Comment: kazemakse you can static assert that (sizeof vec3) == 3* sizeof (float)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yep, that makes sense. However, I did not have a compiler to test the example :)

Comment: also see glm's [extension](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/api/a00183.html#details) `glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp` which "handles the interaction between pointers and vector, matrix types" (and coincidentally confirms the use of [&vec.x](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/blob/ccb25c8/glm/gtc/type_ptr.inl#L77)).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by humbletim in the comment above, I would use glm::value_ptr defined in glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp

```
std::vector<glm::vec3> vec;
vec.push_back(glm::vec3(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f));
vec.push_back(glm::vec3(0.3f, 0.4f, 0.5f));
vec.push_back(glm::vec3(0.7f, 0.8f, 0.9f));

float* flat_array = static_cast<float*>(glm::value_ptr(vec.front()));
std::cout << std::endl;
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size()*(vec.front().length()); ++i ) {
    std::cout << flat_array[i] << std::endl;
}
```